# Filter lowest value within range in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
df <- data.frame (ptid  = c(1,1,1,1, 1, 2,2,2,3,3,3, 3),
              labid = c("CRE", "CRE", "CRE", "CRE", "CRE", "CRE", "CRE", "CRE", "CRE","CRE", "CRE", "CRE"),
              age = c(50, 54, 50.7,  51.3, 51, 52, 35, 37, 46, 46.1, 46.1, 46.1))
```

Within the same participant (same ptid), I would like to keep only rows with the age only if ages are within 2.0 years.

This is what I want my result to look like:

```
result <- data.frame(ptid = c(1,1,2,2,3),
                     labid = c("CRE", "CRE", "CRE", "CRE", "CRE"),
                     age = c(50,54,52,35,46))
```

Thank you in advance for your help! I've really been struggling with this one!

Comment: Within 2 years of what? Like keep the rows that are no more than 2 years above the minimum for each group?

Comment: Not quite. Say there are 3 ages: 35, 50, 51. I want to keep only 35 and 50. 35 is the lowest age. I keep 50 because it is more than 2 years above 35. I exclude 51 because it is within 2 years of 50.

Answer (score 1):

We could do an `arrange` and use `diff` in `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   arrange(ptid, age) %>% 
   group_by(ptid) %>% 
   filter(c(first(age), diff(age)) > 2) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#   ptid labid   age
#  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
#1     1 CRE      50
#2     1 CRE      54
#3     2 CRE      35
#4     2 CRE      52
#5     3 CRE      46
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ptid)%>%
  arrange(ptid, age) %>%
  mutate(grp = cumsum(cumsum(c(0, diff(age)))>2))%>%
  group_by(ptid, grp)%>%
  slice(1) %>%
  ungroup()%>%
  select(-grp)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
   ptid labid   age
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
1     1 CRE      50
2     1 CRE      54
3     2 CRE      35
4     2 CRE      52
5     3 CRE      46
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a function `f` that either `cut`s the input into intervals and identifies duplicates, or gives back smallest element if it fails. Then, apply `f` on each `ptid` level using `ave` with a negation `!`, where you get the number of intervals to `cut` into by dividing the difference of maximum and minimum `age` by 2.

```
f <- function(x, ...) tryCatch(duplicated(cut(x, ...)), error=function(e) order(x) > 1)

res <- subset(df, !ave(age, ptid, FUN=function(x) f(x, diff(range(x)) / 2)))
res
#   ptid labid age
# 1    1   CRE  50
# 2    1   CRE  54
# 6    2   CRE  52
# 7    2   CRE  35
# 9    3   CRE  46
```

**Notes: 1.** The order of observations won't get confused. **2.** The solution removes duplicates aka ties, i.e. if there were more ptid-labid with the same age. (If this should not be desired for any reason, look into `rank()` instead of `order()`.)